# Unicode Basics on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, unicode

I have a C++ library which I deliver to other developers. One of them needs i18n, so he asked me if I could add L prefix to the strings in the API.

I don't know much about i18n so I have some basic questions:

1. When I compile my lib with Unicode, can other developers use this build as usual ? Or shall developers also change their Visual Studio settings to use unicode ?
2. When I compile my lib with Unicode, do I need to change all the strings in headers and .cpp files? Or is it sufficient to add L prefix to strings in header files ?

Thanks in advance!

Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the L prefix changes the string from a `char` array into a `short` array. A better alternative is to wrap all your strings with the "TEXT" macro, i.e.

```
TEXT("My string")
```

If your build is a Unicode build, all your strings become an array of `short`s, but if not, they remain as an array of `char`s. Windows also provides the following types:

```
LPWSTR = short *

LPTSTR = short *, or char * if UNICODE not defined

LPSTR = char *
```

Don't forget though; even though you've prefixed L or wrapped `TEXT` to your strings, you need to make sure you're calling the right functions. Standard Windows string API such as `lstrlen` automatically switch from `char *` to `short *` if `UNICODE` is defined, but you'll need to make sure you're not using functions that only use `char *`.

Functions that your library exports that use strings will also break older applications that use your library since those applications will still be passing and array of `char`s rather than `short`s, so you'll probably want to work in some sort of backwards compatibility in there.

Comment: The L prefix makes the string a wchar_t array, not short.
The confusion probably comes from the fact that, in the old MSVC6, wchar_t was not a native type, but only a typedef for short (or was it unsigned short?)

Comment: wchar_t is still a typedef for unsigned short in MSVC 2008. Look at crtdefs.h.

Comment: There's a compiler options which turn wchar_t in a basic type, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dh8che7s(VS.71).aspx, if I'm not wrong this is the default setting since VS 2005.

Comment: The point of using a typedef is so that you can write code ignorant of the underlying type.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot more than Unicode support to internationalization (i18n). Off the top of my head, there is:

- Currency
- Number representation
- Text encodings (partially abstracted by the use of Unicode)
- Right-to-left scripts
- Text translation mechanisms

Most of this is available in some form or another through APis on Window, whether it be Win32 or .Net, etc. I suggest you take a look at:

- [Microsoft .Net Internationalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688096.aspx)
- [The Microsoft Win32 Internationalization Checklist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194756.aspx)